# how does initializing structs work in c#?

Tags: c#

im currently going through a game tutorial in c# and since i dont know almost anything about the language simple stuff looks confusing.

in my class i have something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public struct TileStruct
{
    public TileDataStruct[] Layer;
    public byte Type;
    public int Data;
    public byte DirBlock;
    }

public TileStruct[,] Tile;
```

first question is what does `[,]` mean here?

second, it is initialized like this:

`Tile = new TileStruct[(byteValue), (byteValue)]`

1) why are two values passed to TileStruct? Where do they end up?

2) why are the values passed in parentheses?

Comment: That's a two-dimensional array: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Comment: two dimensional array of TileStructs?

Comment: Yes, `public TileStruct[,] Tile` declares a member variable that is a two-dimensional array of `TileStruct`s

Answer (score 1):

```
public TileStruct[,] Tile;
```

This part declares public variable named `Tile`. `TileStruct[,]` means this variable holds a reference to a two dimensional array which contains instances of `TileStruct`. You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays).

```
Tile = new TileStruct[(byteValue), (byteValue)]
```

This line creates new instance of two dimensional array I've mentioned earlier and assigns it to `Tile` variable. `[(byteValue), (byteValue)]` declares size of this array in each dimension. Those values are not passed to `TileStruct` in any way. There's no need for parentheses around `byteValue` and deleting them won't change anything.